# how to make a pull request on Git from a cloned branch stored in external folder?

Tags: git, external, git-branch, repository, pull-request

I'm lost with Git...

I have a forked repository `abc` both on Git and locally. I need to create a clone of a branch of the original repo in a separate directory (let's say `abc_branch_1.1`, modify things and then make a pull request to the same branch on the original forked repo.

I can't get it work.

I managed to clone the branch into it's on folder (`external_branches/`), added my stuff and am ready to commit.

Problem is, my online forked repo knows nothing about branch `abc_branch_1.1` in folder `external_branches/`? I thought the branch should be there, but it's not.

**Question:**
Any idea how to solve this Git puzzle = get my "external" branch to be in the actual repo (both locally and online) so I can make the PR on the branch in the repo, I forked from?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
So I set the remote to:

git remote set-url origin git@github.com:my_username/forked_repo

When I then modify, add, commit and try to push, I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

When I check status:

```
Your branch is ahead of origin/abc_branch_1.1 by 1 commit
```

Still clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that with "both on Git and locally", you actually mean "both on Github and locally" or any other similar git repository hosting platform.

When you have cloned from your fork locally, than you do not need to clone anymore. Especially, branching is done in the same local repository and directory, you do not need to copy anything. So it is different from other systems like Subversion. There is actually documentation on that on the internet, like http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

To solve your puzzle, it probably boils down to

```
git checkout -b abc_branch_1.1
<-- make modifications -->
<-- commit the modifications -->
<-- check git status -->
git push -u
```

Comment: ok. I will try that. What if I cloned the branch from the original repo (not the forked one). I probably should just start over...

Comment: just set the url with
git remote set-url origin $theURL  (without dollar)

Comment: I give up for tonight... see my edit above. Thanks so far. I think I'm halfway...

Comment: This actually sounds pretty good already. Try "git push -n" now, it will tell you the commit range it will push to the server (something like abc...def) and where it will push to. -n stands for dry-run so nothing actually happens with that flag turned on. To be sure, do "git log -p abc...def" and check your changes.  (Do not forget to push without -n at the end).

Comment: I can't push a single space... I'm told I'm ahead by 1 commit locally. When I pull, I get a ton of merge conflicts (since I tested committing only a single space in one file, probably not because of me). So still stuck, but posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798964/how-to-make-a-pull-request-on-git-from-a-cloned-branch-stored-in-external-folder). I will check yours, because I think it's all correct